# SQL Server 2005 Job Schedule

Tags: sql-server

Can we schedule a Stored Procedure to run every 3 seconds in SQL server 2005 ?
I could not find a way to schedule it so currently i am calling from front-end.
The schedular interface allow minimum 1 minute of scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule it every minute to run 20 times in a loop with waitfor delay 3 seconds. Or even to run continuously in a loop with 3 second waitfor delays.

In SQL 2005 and on you can use [Conversation Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) to launch activated procedures at 1 second resolution timer.

On a side note, I highly doubt such scheduling is ever necessary.

Comment: +1:That's an interesting solution, although I also agree with your final point.

Comment: Rusanu,
Thanks for your response. it is a real world need to call it every 3 secodns. the application is ruuning fine. i just want to do it in background so i do not need to run a exe to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about run shcedule every 3 seconds, but you can write in step multiple invokes of your procedure with waitfor procedure:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:01'
```

Comment: X2,
It is great. so what is the best way 
WHILE TRUE
BEGIN
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:03'
 EXECUTE @n = dbo.WorkerSP
END